# Converting int array to char*

Tags: c++

Is this possible? I wanted to convert this into a char* so I could later retrieve this values.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? Do you want an array of strings with your numbers in them? Do you want to access your int's one byte at a time?

Comment: Pretty much anything, as long as I can retrieve all the ints later.

Comment: Are you trying to preserve data after a function's return, by any chance?

Comment: Well, I was actually send this over the network as a packet.

Comment: Note that one reason to close is "ambiguous".

Comment: @Potatoswatter- I think this question is quite simple- yes or no?

Comment: @seed: No, it could mean interpreting the array as a `char*` or converting the numbers to some string.

Comment: And interpreting an int array as char* for transmission over network is an endian problem waiting to happen (maybe not now, but sometime down the line...).

Comment: Sort of edited question, is it better?

Comment: Not really.  It's like asking if you can do math in C++.

Comment: @seed: You should really ask about what you're trying to do (how do I transmit ints over the network) not about how to do it the way you think you're going to (convert int[] to char*).

Comment: @Jefromi- I already have a question open, no replies. It might be too specific though (uses a Network library)

Comment: @seed: Perhaps you should edit that question to provide a little more information and bump it up - in particular, are you stuck with that particular library, or do you have other options?

Comment: @jefromi- I think the question is pretty clear. I guess I could go with normal winsockets, but I'm not sure if it makes much difference.

Comment: @seed: A lot of the point was just to bump it back up, and make sure your question was clear so you'll get as many answers there as you have here. At the very least you can add a couple tags (it's a windows C++ networking question, not just a networking question). Or maybe the answers below about serialization have been enough.

Comment: @jefromi- Okay, I think I'll try winsocks as it is most likely way more popular and reformulate some tags.

Answer (score 8):

Sure:

```
int array[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(array);
```

The valid range is from `c` to `c + sizeof(array)`. You are allowed to do this to any POD type.

You can cast back from a sequence of bytes:

```
// assuming c above
int (&pArray)[4] = *reinterpret_cast<int(*)[4]>(c);
```

This is guaranteed to work. But, it seems you're trying to send stuff across a network, which can introduce other problems

---

The process you're looking for is called *serialization* (and has a [FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html)). This is when you take an object, transform it into a series of bits, which can later be "deserialized" into the original object.

Making this work across multiple platforms can be tricky, because you need to make sure you serialize into a specific format, and that each platform knows how it should read from that format. (For example, a big-endian platform might always convert to little-endian before sending, and likewise convert back to big-endian when receiving.) You cannot treat non-POD types as a stream of bytes (such as `std::string`), so you need to write serialization functions for those, to transform their data into a stream of bytes, and deserialization functions to transform it back.

I particularly like that way Boost does this, and if you can I'd use their [serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). They basically first define routines for serializing fundamental types, then you can serialize more complex types by building off that. Of course, Boost also has their [ASIO library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to do sockets for you.

Comment: Ideally the last element in the array would be a zero in case someone down the line  passes the char* to a str* function

Comment: That intention isn't explicitly stated in the question though.

Comment: This seemed to have worked, but just wondering- how do I get the actual data from it? For example, if I printed this out, it actually gave me a smiley face symbol (=D)- I'm guessing that's what 1234 represents or something. Can I actually disassembles this back into 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @seed: if it prints a smiley, that means that the last byte of the first int (assuming little-endian) equals the DOS character value for the smiley.

Comment: @George Edison: It prints a smiley? Awesome! I'm going to try this out now! :)

Comment: @Frustrated: Haha, it totally does print a smiley. I'm badass and clearly planned this out.

Comment: No, you're pretty much asking for trouble if you're trying to serialize or deserialize.  If that's what you want, go read up on `snprintf` and `sscanf`.

Comment: Okay, so what other options do I have?

Comment: @seed: not too many other options. As @Mike mentioned, you should look into `sprintf`.

Comment: I tried `int (&pArray)[4] = *reinterpret_cast<int(*)[4]>(c);` that Gman added, and I guess I can't really test it with printf, which is what I'm using, because I always have to convert it to a char anyways.

Comment: I _think_ that the cast `char* -> int[4]` is only valid if the `char*`  was obtained from a cast `int[4] -> char*`.  Otherwise it doesn't obey the strict aliasing rules (e.g., if you read an array of bytes from a file, you can't just cast the `char*` obtained from the file into an `int[4]`, you have to cast the `int[4]` to a `char*` and then copy the bytes from the file into the `int[4]`).

Comment: That's what I'm doing, no? I'm converting an int[] to char, then back to int[].

Comment: @seed:  Yes; I just wanted to clarify.  Maybe I just made it more confusing... I'm good at doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you probably shouldn't.

Doing so will treat the ints as sequences of bytes. It is tempting to then pass these bytes to be written to files or across sockets. The problem is that that the result will not be portable. There is no guarantee that whatever computer reads those bytes will interpret them in the same way. The biggest issue is big-endian vs little-endian. Essentially, some computers  put the most significant byte first whereas others put the least significant byte first. Switching between them will result in the number being read backwards.

Comment: Ah yes, I read about this.... while I guess it is a very bad idea, I'll just try it, it's more of an experiment than something that'll go on the market ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use C-style, but in C++:

```
int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
char* p_arr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string, use `std::string`, not `char*`. If you want serialization, use `<stringstream>`.

```
#include <stringstream>

std::ostringstream packet_os;
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i ) packet_os << arr[ i ] << " ";
network_send( packet_os.str().c_str() ); // c_str() returns char*
```

On the other end:

```
network_receive( recv_buf );
std::istringstream packet_is( recv_buf->bytes );
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i ) packet_is >> arr[ i ];
assert ( packet_is ); // for debugging, check that everything was received OK
```

Comment: @seed: sorry, I was writing a code comment as you wrote your question comment.

Comment: Okay, I see.  (Not enough chars so I'll put this in).

Comment: @seed: Especially considering "The params for a function only accept char*", this would seem to completely answer your question. Is that not the case?

Comment: @potatoswatter- Yeah, but I think I just need a way of turning it back.

Comment: @potatoswatter- I'm guessing network_send is pseudo function?

Comment: @seed: right, in the absence of any other kind of specification.

Comment: @potatoswatter- I think it's either the console or maybe the network which messes up this data, so I've opened a new thread directly related to networking. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score -1):

This what you're looking to do?

```
int list[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

char * pChar = (char *)list;
```